# How to convert scripts/get_maintainer.pl output as input to mutt or git-send email?

Tags: linux-kernel

I create a `.patch`, then:

```
scripts/get_maintainer.pl 0001-my-patch.patch
```

and that gives output of format:

```
Josh Poimboeuf <jpoimboe@redhat.com> (maintainer:LIVE PATCHING)
Jessica Yu <jeyu@kernel.org> (maintainer:LIVE PATCHING)
linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org (open list:BPF (Safe dynamic programs and tools))
live-patching@vger.kernel.org (open list:LIVE PATCHING)
```

on Linux v4.17.

Is there any way to feed that output to either `mutt` or `git send-email` to save some copy paste time?

The help gives a hint at:

```
  Using "--roles" or "--rolestats" with git send-email --cc-cmd or any
      other automated tools that expect only ["name"] <email address>
      may not work because of additional output after <email address>.
```

but let's just document it clearly here to save other people some time.

Answer (score 4):

The kernel documentation [suggests doing this manually](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/submitting-patches.html#select-the-recipients-for-your-patch), using the roles output by `get_maintainer.pl` to decide which recipients to include.

However, if you know `get_maintainer.pl` does the right thing, you can get it to produce output that will work as input to MUAs or `git send-email` by adding the `--no-rolestats` and `--separator=,` options:

```
scripts/get_maintainer.pl --separator=, --no-rolestats 0001-my-patch.patch
```

You can use this in `cc-cmd` to fill in carbon copies:

```
git send-email --cc-cmd="scripts/get_maintainer.pl --separator=, --no-rolestats" 0001-my-patch.patch
```

but that will strip the mailing lists, and won’t help you fill in the main recipients (which should include the maintainers and at least one of the mailing lists). It will still save you some copy-pasting, as requested.